# libGDX : my camera doesn't follow my sprite image(Player)

Tags: android, camera, libgdx, sprite, orthographic

I am just started using libgdx , I am a newbie in game development and I want that my camera follows my sprite but it doesn't follow my sprite(Player) but rather sprite just move back and forth very little and not going upward(as I want).

Here is my show() method

```
 public void show() {
        world = new World(new Vector2(0, 25), true);
        renderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();
        cam = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        cam.position.set(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2, 0);
        cam.update();

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputController() {
            @Override
            public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
                if(keycode == Input.Keys.A)
                    box.setLinearVelocity(0f, 60f);
                if(keycode == Input.Keys.D)
                    box.setLinearVelocity(0f, 20f);
                if(keycode == Input.Keys.ESCAPE)
                    ((Game) Gdx.app.getApplicationListener()).setScreen(new MainMenu());
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
                if(keycode == Input.Keys.A)
                    box.setLinearVelocity(0f, 0f);
                if(keycode == Input.Keys.D)
                    box.setLinearVelocity(0f, 0f);

                return true;
            }
        });


        shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        texture = new Texture("img/imgs.png");
        sprite = new Sprite(texture);
        sprite.setSize(47, 45);
        sprite.setOrigin(sprite.getWidth()/2, sprite.getHeight()/2);
        sprite.setBounds(200, 200, 64, 64);
        //sprite.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2 -sprite.getWidth()/2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2-sprite.getHeight()/2);



        //Body definition
        BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
        bodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
        bodyDef.position.set(0, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2 - 250);

        box = world.createBody(bodyDef);

        //Polygon Shape
        PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
        shape.setAsBox(10, 20);


        //fixture definition
        FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
        fixtureDef.shape = shape;
        fixtureDef.density = 5f;
        fixtureDef.friction = .5f;

        box.createFixture(fixtureDef);

        box.setUserData(sprite);


        shape.dispose();
```

Here is my render method

```
public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        world.step(1/60f, 6, 2);


        cam.position.set(0,sprite.getY()+sprite.getHeight()/2,0);


        cam.update();

        batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);

        batch.disableBlending();
        batch.begin();
        world.getBodies(tmpBodies);
        for(Body body: tmpBodies)
            if(body.getUserData() instanceof  Sprite){
                Sprite boxsprite = (Sprite) body.getUserData();
                boxsprite.setPosition(body.getPosition().x - sprite.getHeight()/2, body.getPosition().y- sprite.getHeight()/2);
                boxsprite.setRotation(body.getAngle() * MathUtils.radiansToDegrees);
                boxsprite.draw(batch);
            }
        batch.end();

        shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.RED);
        shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
        shapeRenderer.rect(0, 200, 50, 50);
        shapeRenderer.translate(1, 0, 0);
        shapeRenderer.end();

        renderer.render(world, cam.combined);
    }
```

And Here is my resize method

```
 public void resize(int width, int height) {
        cam.viewportWidth = width;
        cam.viewportHeight = height;
        cam.update();


    }
```

I've tried every possible solution but couldn't get the desired result.
I just want that my camera follows my sprite and also sprite does work properly.
please help me to provide the better solution. Thank you in advance

Comment: I am not really familiar with Box2D, but I think your problem is that your sprite doesn't move only your body does. Try to set the camera position to your body position.

Comment: OK, actually I'm a novice in game development so I don't know how to set body position to camera position. If you know the answer would you please help me thanks

Comment: Something like this maybe? : cam.position.set(body.getPosition().x - Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2,body.getPosition().y +Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2,0);

Comment: no sorry, it didn't work any more suggestions